# JWT deauthentication in React Redux App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, jwt

I am having a tiny issue wrapping my head around how I would go about deauthenticating a user in the most efficient manner in my React/Redux application. (Using Redux Thunk as well).

Getting the token from the server is a piece of cake. Currently I:

```
- Send POST request with email and pw
- Receive Token back from server
- Save it to local storage.
```

Any additional requests after that to the server requires attaching the token inside an AUTHORIZATION header, which is fine.

Lets say that I walk away from the app after being logged in for awhile, then come back and decide to try to view another protected route. Lets call this route, "/latest-videos", which sends out an AJAX request to fetch the latest videos.

When that request is sent, the server determines that my token has expired, and will not allow me access to this resource. Obviously, this is where I would want to implement some type of action creator in Redux that will go ahead and redirect the user to the login page.

Do I need to perform some type of check on every AJAX request to see if the token has expired? It seems like doing that would require unnecessary boilerplate in every file that I have an AJAX request written.

This is where things get muddy for me. If we assume the token has a predetermined expiration date, **how can I go about deauthenticating a user in the most efficient manner, without filling my app with poor code design choices?**

You can assume I have a folder in my app called "actions" that contains files like so:

```
- actions
   - videos.js
   - users.js
   - projects.js
   - ...
```

Within a given file inside of the actions folder, you could have multiple Thunks that perform AJAX calls. Here is boilerplate example of what one of them may look like:

```
export function fetchVideos(query) {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch({ type: FETCH_VIDEOS })

      let res = await axios.post(`${API_URL}/videos/search`, {
        query: query
      })
      // dispatch some success action creator with the data
    }
    catch(e) {
      console.error('ERROR FETCHING VIDEOS: ' + e)
      dispatch({ type: FETCH_VIDEOS_FAILED })
    }
  }
}
```

Hopefully I am making some sense...any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to check the token in your react app. Your server should be the one checking your token’s validity/expiry upon every request.

Since we’re talking about client application consuming restful api calls, server should be the one restricting the resources upon invalid token and return the 401 unauthorized response.

Upon that response, client app should deauthenticate a user and redirect to the login page (or send a request with a refresh token if you have any to avoid unnecessary login action).

Comment: Yeah I mean that's what I was getting at. So in every catch block of every ajax request I need to check for a 401 unauthorized?

Comment: That’s right. There needs to be a contract between a server and a client to know when your authorization has failed. Instead of writing that check in each of the `catch` blocks, you could perhaps dry that out by writing a separate service or a class that handles your networking logic, or could utilize axios’ interceptors.

Comment: Thanks man. Yeah, that was one big concern for me,  sticking to dry as much as possible. I will most certainly check out your recommendations